# Google seach query without omitting similar results

Tags: google-search

Many times google omits search results which are similar (you can click on the last results page to show the omitted ones). How can I query google search without omitting the similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append `&filter=0` to the end of the query URL. The *filter* parameter disables automatic filtering, which disables both the filtering of *duplicate content* and *host crowding*.

As far as I can tell, this is exactly what the "*repeat the search with the omitted results included*" link does.

However, there is no way to make this permanent as far as I can tell.

For more information:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#automaticFiltering

Comment: Hmm I actually wanted something in the search query (a flag similar to: "site: www.example.com") but that will have to do

Comment: AFAIK there are no [search operators](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861) that will do a similar thing unfortunately.

Comment: In that case topic closed, thanks for the right answer!